# Is there an R package similar to JMBayes for the joint modelling of a continuous and a categorical outcome?

Tags: r

I would like to create a joint model of a continuous variable (time between two events) and a categorical outcome (0 or 1) according to two different categorical variables.

I have found the JMBayes package in R but this only serves for longitudinal and time-to-event data and that is not what I need. I have been searching to find a similar package for any type of outcome but everything seems to be linked with the longitudinal and time-to-event approach explained by Dimitris Rizopoulos.

Is there any package for what I want?

Thanks in advance